# Steamlined way of reading a file with zig

Tags: zig

I have a file with a bunch of primes. For this purpose we can say that the contents of this file called "primes" are as follows:

```
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,
```

I want to read the contents of this file (and do some other unrelated stuff later on).

My problem is that the way am reading the file seems to have boilerplate and also appears to be very amateur. This is what i have

```
const std = @import("std");
const print = std.debug.print;

pub fn main() void {
    print("This is the beginning of the program\n", .{});

    const file: std.fs.File = std.fs.cwd().openFile(
        "primes",
        .{}) catch | err | {
        print("En arror occured while opening file: {}\n", .{err});
        std.os.exit(1);
    };
    defer file.close();

    const reader = file.reader();
    var buff: [1024]u8 = undefined;

    while(reader.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(&buff, ',')) | number | {  // THIS IS A PROBLEM LINE
        if(number == null) break;                                   // AND SO IS THIS
        print("...running {s}\n", .{buff});
    } else | err | {
        print("En arror occured while opening file: {}\n", .{err});
    }

    print("Buffer: {s}\n", .{buff});
}
```

It seems redundant and almost dumb to unpack the value onto "number" while the buffer "buff" will also have the same contents, unless "number" is null (which will break the loop). I want to know if there is a more streamline way to do this..

I am avoiding using the return value of *!void* in the main function because I am trying to practice error handling, and want to handle them myself.

Comment: I don't think that this code is working as expected. `buff` is an array, not a string. You want to print the value in `number`, which is itself an error union with an optional value. You certainly should not attempt to print the contents of `buff` when an error occurs in the `while` loop. Since this question seems better-suited to Stack Overflow, where you originally posted, I have posted [an answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78235198/6879826).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is cross posted from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78212507/steamlined-way-of-reading-a-file-with-zig)

Comment: @adabsurdum Good Job! When you comment on SO that a question doesn't belong on CR, the link you should add is to the help page https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help so that they understand why it would be off-topic.

Comment: @pacmaninbw This same question was suggested to be posted on here. So i did.

Comment: @adabsurdum this code does work. The buffer is printed as a string with the "{s}" format specifier.

Comment: @Hackerman -- the buffer is not a string. This code prints the entire buffer, all 1024 bytes of it, each time the loop reads a new segment of the file. Is that your intent?

Comment: @adabsurdum I understand that I should not use this approach in the future. My intent was to see to only print  each section at a time (similar to how "getline" works in c). It could be that it worked out of "dumb" luck, and it didn't print garbage next to the data I wanted. I believe you answered this question on SO. THanks for the input.

Comment: @Hackerman -- if you compile in debug mode the undefined bytes are given the value 0xAA, but if you compile in a release mode the undefined bytes are just undefined.

Comment: That just sounds like a headache waiting to happen for someone somewhere. Thanks for letting me know. My takeaway from this is that the buffer I pass is the users’ way to specify what resources to use. It actually sounds fairly clever

Comment: Anyone looking for the explanation to this question can find it [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78212507/steamlined-way-of-reading-a-file-with-zig?noredirect=1#comment137926904_78212507), there was some back and forth with where this question should have been posted.

Comment: My apologies for causing all of this.